# Struts2 <filter> and <filter-mapping> causing error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration, struts2

I have a web application using Eclipse, Struts2, and running on a Tomcat 7 Server.

I've been going off of the http://javabrains.koushik.org tutorials.

I have all the basic Struts pieces in place, but for some reason when I introduce this snippet of code into the `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<filter-mapping>
```

It throws the book at me.

```
SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
Unable to load configuration. - bean -
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean -     
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already  been loaded by bean - 
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2    
Unable to load configuration. - bean -     
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean -     
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean -    
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name struts has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar!/struts-default.xml:40:72
- bean -
```

I know this isn't the complete text dump but I don't know how useful the rest of it would be. I need to understand why it's doing this so I can get it working.

Comment: need more info. post the whole web.xml and struts.xml

Comment: **I am getting the same error. But if i run same program in MyEclipse . It is working.
I think may be some Class Path issue is there. but not sure.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. It turns out all I needed to do is to forget the build path and only put the jars into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 3):

You should not copy application specific jars to the server `lib` folder. Instead use `WEB-INF/lib`. Remove `struts2-core-2.3.16.jar` from the server `lib`. If you have another `struts2-core-x.x.x.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` it prevents Tomcat to deploy your application because libraries from the Tomcat `lib` folder loading before any application is being deployed. It stops the deployment. Tomcat `lib` folder should contain only Tomcat installed jars needed to run the web container, there's no need to copy there other jars unless you know what are you doing.